# java fx remove stackPane

Tags: java, javafx

I need help creating a delete button on a stack pane in JavaFX.
It should remove the chosen stack pane from the group.
RinStackPane is extended javafx StackPane, gp is java fx Group.
Thank you in advance!
Here is my code:

```
private void setOnCreateMathOperation(Button createMathOperationBtn) {
    createMathOperationBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
        var mathOperation = createMathOperation();

        RinStackPane stack1 = new RinStackPane();
        stack1.setNodeType(NodesTypes.MathOperation);
        stack1.setUnderlyingNode(mathOperation);

        stack1.setName(mathOperation.getName());
        stack1.getChildren().add(mathOperation);

        TextField newtf1 = new TextField();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.addRow(1, newtf1);
        stack1.getChildren().add(grid);

        makeDraggable(stack1);
        addToRectCollection(stack1);

        gp.getChildren().add(stack1);
    });
}
```

Comment: `gp.getChildren().remove(stack1)` will remove it. Just execute that in the handler for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to keep the delete button inside or outside the StackPane.

Anyway you can easily bind an [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) to the Group's children. When an elemente will be deleted from the list, automatically this event will be reflected on Group's children:

```java
//Create observable list of Node (you can constrain to RinStackPane if you prefer):
ObservableList<Node> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//bind lists to gp's children:
Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(list, gp.getChildren());
```

Your code:

```java
private void setOnCreateMathOperation(Button createMathOperationBtn) {
    createMathOperationBtn.setOnAction(event -> {

        RinStackPane stack1 = new RinStackPane();
        //...
        //setup the stack
        //...

        //Add the delete button to the stack:
        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete me!");
        deleteButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            list.remove(stack1); //<--- remove action
        });
        stack1.getChildren().add(deleteButton);

        //add to the list instead of gp's children
        list.add(stack1);
    });
}
```

Note how the stack is not added nor removed to/from the gp's children, instead the `list` is used.

If you want the deleteButton *outside* the stack the code is the same, just be sure that both `list` and `stack1` are somehow passed to the button's click handler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It’s not really clear what the point of the additional list is. Why not just do `gp.getChildren().remove(stack1)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Imagine you have a more complex model (e.g. `ObservableList <MyObject>`), with a proper binding you don't bother manipulating the views around in the code. Binding results in a powerful mechanism for the MVC pattern.

Comment: Yes, true, in a way. However you can't use a binding directly in that case, as the object types are different; you'd need some more complex listeners set up between the two lists. But in a MVC-designed app this would be the way to structure it.